# How to resolve the "Cannot delete or update a parent row" error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling

I keep getting:

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails on MySQL.

It only appears on "drop table if exists branches" and "drop table if exists staff", but the rest is function correctly.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Optician;
USE Optician;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS branches;
CREATE TABLE branches (
  branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  branch_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  branch_address ENUM('Cardiff', 'Swansea', 'Newport') NOT NULL,
  staff_available BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS staff;
CREATE TABLE staff (
  staff_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  staff_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  staff_role ENUM('Optician', 'Receptionist', 'Technician') NOT NULL,
  staff_available BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
  welsh_speaker BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
  branch_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) 
  REFERENCES branches(branch_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS appointments;
CREATE TABLE appointments (
  appointment_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  appointment_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  appointment_date DATE NOT NULL,
  appointment_time TIME NOT NULL,
  staff_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (staff_id) 
  REFERENCES staff(staff_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE (appointment_date, appointment_time, staff_id)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  customer_phone VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
  customer_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  order_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  order_status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  order_date DATE NOT NULL,
  technician_id INT NOT NULL,
  lens_arrival_date DATE,
  assembly_start_date DATE,
  assembly_completion_date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (technician_id) 
  REFERENCES staff(staff_id)
);
```

Comment: You need to drop in order appointments,staff, branches in other words the table containg the FK has to be dropped before you can drop the referenced table..also is there a reason why you want to drop?

Comment: The reason why I drop is because when I remove drop, I receive an error called if table 1050 don't exist. I am new to MYSQL, so I am trying to figure stuff out.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment ' when I remove drop, I receive an error called if table 1050 don't exist' - what are you doing to throw this error?

Answer (score 0):

The First time you run the code there is no problem because referenced tables need to be created before referencing tables (those with FKs). When you run the code again the referencing tables(those with FKs) have to be dropped before the referenced tables can be dropped.

Alternatively if the database consists of all the tables you wish to drop you could drop the database and run the code again.

In real world aps it's unusual that tables are dropped in order to make table changes once a DB is up an running and more usual that ALTER table is used for amending tables.